# Discord.js | Kicking and Banning

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I've tried to look for answers on the internet but they still didn't work for me, I just want to know how to kick someone and ban them and what the code would be(I am using discord.js v12)

Comment: I just entered your exact question title in [enter search engine here] and found many many results and examples: https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/docs/examples/moderation.md please show the code you have tried, maybe we can make it work

Comment: thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
GuildMember.ban({
    reason: "Reason",
    days: 50
}).catch(e => console.log(e));

GuildMember.kick("Reason").catch(e => console.log(e));
```